# Can I chain Bulk API jobs?

Tags: relationships, bulk-api, concurrency, jobs

I have to load millions of records in a data migration process and I'm dealing with a parent object and a couple of custom child objects. After initial load, data will keep flowing, as Salesforce has to ingest data from an external loyalty system.
I understood that batches within a job may run in parallel, or serially (only in parallel for Bulk API 2.0), but I don't know if the different jobs (one for each object) will run in parallel or not. I need the job for the parent object to complete before the other jobs start, because otherwise I would not be able to set the lookup fields.

Comment: What stops you from loading all parent records in parallel, determining the status of this (single) job, then loading all children in parallel?

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing your own script, you can certainly chain them however you wish to.

Here is a simple Node.js script showing how to achieve this,

```
const jsforce = require('jsforce');
const sfbulk = require('node-sf-bulk2');
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  if (process.env.username && process.env.password) {
    const conn = new jsforce.Connection({});
    await conn.login(process.env.username, process.env.password);
    const bulkconnect = {
        'accessToken': conn.accessToken,
        'apiVersion': '51.0',
        'instanceUrl': conn.instanceUrl
    };
    try {
        // create a new BulkAPI2 class
        const bulkrequest = new sfbulk.BulkAPI2(bulkconnect);
        // create a bulk insert job
        const jobRequestAccountUpload = {
            'object': 'Account',
            'operation': 'insert'
        };
        const response = await bulkrequest.createDataUploadJob(jobRequestAccountUpload);
        if (response.id) {
            // read csv data from the local file system
            const data = await util.promisify(fs.readFile)(process.cwd() + "/account.csv", "UTF-8");
            const status = await bulkrequest.uploadJobData(response.contentUrl, data);
            if (status === 201) {
                // close the job for processing
                await bulkrequest.closeOrAbortJob(response.id, 'UploadComplete');
                // Now start doing Contact upload
                // create a new BulkAPI2 class
        const bulkrequest = new sfbulk.BulkAPI2(bulkconnect);
        // create a bulk insert job for contact
        const jobRequestContactUpload = {
            'object': 'Contact',
            'operation': 'insert'
        };

         const response = await bulkrequest.createDataUploadJob(jobRequestContactUpload);
            }
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
    }
  } else {
    throw 'set environment variable with your orgs username and password'
  }
})();
```

You might need some sort of temporary table or have to use an externalID to make sure you relate Parent and child records.